# VB Search for String in Excel and Return Offset Cells Value to Another String

Tags: vb.net

I started a new question as it was difficult to show the code updates in the comments section.

Below is my incomplete code, I need to find wd_full in the DDDL workbook as below, move 1 cell to the right and then return that value to the string found

The piece I have "commented" out was the old method I used to find the folder and takes too long. The DDDL spread sheet has 2 columns, column a is the design ref and column be is the folder path.

```
Private Sub GoBut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoBut.Click

    Dim wdcode As String
    wdcode = TextCode.Text
    Dim wd_wild As String
    wd_wild = "*"
    Dim wd_full As String
    wd_full = wd_wild & wdcode
    Dim found As String
    Dim DDDL As String
    DDDL = "N:\IT\Database\Design Drive Dir List\DDDL.xlsx"

    Dim exApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    exApp.Visible = True
    exApp.Workbooks.Open(DDDL)

    found = Find(wd_full).Offset(0, 1).Value()


    exApp.Quit()

    ' found = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, wd_full).FirstOrDefault()

    MsgBox(wd_full, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Found Directory")

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", found))
End Sub
```

Comment: It's the Find command that is saying it is not declared. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I worked it out - found = exApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(wd_full).Offset(0, 1).Value()